# JavaFX and and getDesktop().open() crashes the program

Tags: java, javafx, awt, gnome

When I try to call `Desktop.getDesktop().open()`, my program crashes.

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 16.10, running Gnome 3.20.4. I haven't had a chance to test this code on another platform, but on this platform it is definitely crashing the program.

```
browseMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        Platform.runLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println ( Desktop.isDesktopSupported() );
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open( albumTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getPath().toFile() );
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any thoughts on how to fix or troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 4):

You're mixing JavaFX and AWT, which is likely causing the problem. Instead of

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

try using the JavaFX API:

```
getHostServices().showDocument(file.toURI().toString());
```

[`getHostServices()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#getHostServices--) is defined in `Application` (so you may need to retrieve it in your start method and pass it to whichever object - perhaps a controller - is registering the listener with the menu item).

Comment: It compiles, but at runtime I get the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.fx.HostServicesFactory

Comment: Google recommends adding "-addmods javafx.deploy", but I get Unrecognized option: -addmods.

OpenJDK and OpenFX

Answer (score 0):

It looks like @James_D's answer is the better way to do things, but currently (as of 2017/05/03) it doesn't work on the OpenJDK / OpenJFK.

Thankfully, his comment about mixing JFX and Swing helped me find a solution which will work on OpenJDK / OpenJFX:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open( albumTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getPath().toFile() );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

The trick was using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` rather than `Platform.runLater()`, since the code inside is swing.

Comment: My solution works for me on Ubuntu 16.04 using OpenJDK/OpenJFX. (I am not really a Ubuntu user and someone set this machine up for me - I'm not sure which windowing toolkit it is using.) This is a viable alternative though.

Comment: In principle, I like your solution better. I added a "TODO" to my code to check to see if it works in six months.